# When I run on android 6.0 I get an error On spinner. But same code works on android version 7, 8,9

Tags: java, android

I am using `Spinner` for displaying some values.

> Its working on other newest android version like 7, 8, 9. But I got an error on android version android 6.0

```
01-13 16:40:14.010 11363-11363/in.codepoetry.callrecordapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: in.codepoetry.callrecordapp, PID: 11363
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.codepoetry.callrecordapp/in.codepoetry.callrecordapp.CRE_Selector}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class Spinner
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2487)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5604)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class Spinner
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at in.codepoetry.callrecordapp.CRE_Selector.onCreate(CRE_Selector.java:43)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6358)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5604) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class Spinner
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:786)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at in.codepoetry.callrecordapp.CRE_Selector.onCreate(CRE_Selector.java:43) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6358) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5604) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/spiner_bg.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070093
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2690)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2580)
        at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:388)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:872)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3963)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:574)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.<init>(AdapterView.java:246)
        at android.widget.AbsSpinner.<init>(AbsSpinner.java:70)
        at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:232)
        at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:199)
        at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:154)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner.<init>(AppCompatSpinner.java:196)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner.<init>(AppCompatSpinner.java:167)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner.<init>(AppCompatSpinner.java:148)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner.<init>(AppCompatSpinner.java:133)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createSpinner(AppCompatViewInflater.java:197)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:118)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.
```

And this is my code where I put data into spinner

```java
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CRE_Selector.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Customer);

dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

customer_list.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Here is my spiner_bg.xml

```
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="-2dp" android:right="-2dp" android:left="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ababb2" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/drop" />
        // you can use any other image here, instead of default_holo_dark_am
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Check this  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/spiner_bg.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070093

Comment: Thank you.
Its working if remove the background. I want to use background.

Comment: please post code

Comment: No problem. Now its working and thankyou very much.

Comment: can I answer it instead of comment so that you can mark as correct answer?

Comment: Vote it and answer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/spiner_bg.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070093

Change this resource file to solve this